# Thumbnail images and screen shots have disappeared after installing booster

Tags: applications

I've had this phone (ALCATEL 918) for a few weeks. I felt it was moving exceptionally slow. So, I downloaded booster.

Then, I noticed that all of the thumbnail images and screen shots have disappeared. Other then that, everything else works fine. How do I fix this?

Comment: What's this "booster" you say you've downloaded? If it's an app, a link to the app would be helpful. All of what thumbnail images and screen shots have disappeared? Is it a problem in one app or several apps? Which one(s)? Exactly what images are missing, and what images still show up? If you can describe your problem precisely, someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

This booster probably deleted all the cache files from your phone and as a result you don't see the thumbnails of your previous photos.

Go to

```
sdcard/DCIM/
```

and delete the .thumbnails folder & restart your phone. That should bring back your thumbnails.

Comment: Glad it worked out :)